# AMP responsive image with a max-height

Tags: css, responsive, amp-html

Can someone tell how to get a responsive image with AMP with a height max limit instead of a fixed height?
Thank you.

At this stage I found this:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="fixed-height-container">
<amp-img data-hero class="contain" width="225px" height="150px" layout="fill" src="/myimage.jpg"></amp-img>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.fixed-height-container {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 100%; 
   height: 380px;
}
amp-img.contain img {
    object-fit: cover;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Is something missing here: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-img/ or here: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/art_direction/

Comment: I'm looking for something like this:  `<div style="width: 100%; max-height: 100px;">
    <amp-img alt="A view of the sea" src="/static/inline-examples/images/sea.jpg" width="900px" height="675px" layout="responsive">
    </amp-img>
  </div>`